# ARM template - Retrieving from keyvault not working when secret name is concatenated

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to retrieve secrets from a Vault within my ARM template

In my parameter file I have the following

```
"resource_Env": {
  "value": "dev"
},

"activation_URI": {
  "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/RG-DEV/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/myVault"
    },
    "secretName": "[concat('activation-URI-', parameters('resource_Env'))]"
  }
}
```

When I run this I get an error

> Error Code: KeyVaultParameterReferenceSecretRetrieveFailed
>           Message: The secret of KeyVault parameter 'activation_URI' cannot be retrieved. Http status code: 'BadRequest'. Error message:
>   'The request URI contains an invalid name: [concat('activation-URI-',
>   parameters('resource_Env'))]'

It appears that the concat is not working.  If I hard code the whole string as in

```
"secretName": "activation-URI-dev"
```

it works fine

Am I unable to concat in the secretName property?

Here is my template file:-

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01- 
    01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
       "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "resource_Env": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "dev"
        },
         "resource_Env_number": {
          "type": "string",
           "defaultValue": "1"
        },
        "resource_Platform": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "int"
        },
        "resource_Group_Locn": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "australiasoutheast"
        },
        "resource_Org": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "eml"
        },
        "typeName_ResourceGroup": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "rg"
        },
        "resourceGroupPrefix": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": " 
    [concat(parameters('resource_Env'),parameters('resource_Env_Number'),'-',parameters('resource_Org'),'-',parameters('resource_Platform'))]"
        },
        "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "   
   [concat(parameters('resource_Env'),parameters('resource_Env_Number'),'-eml-int-svcbus')]",
              "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Service Bus namespace"
              }
            },
            "serviceBusTopicName": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "transaction",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the Topic"
           }
        },
        "typeName_FuncApp": {
          "defaultValue": "func",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ocp_apim_subscription_key": {
          "defaultValue": "",
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Subscription key for APIM"
          }
        },
        "svcbus_connection_string": {
          "defaultValue": "",
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Service bus connection string"
          }
        },
        "activation_URI": {
          "defaultValue": "",
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "The URI to the activate endpoint"
          }
        },
        "webhookid": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "The id of the webhook registered with EML"
          }
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "string",
          "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "Location for all resources."
          }
        }
      },
      "variables": {
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
          "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
          "name": "serviceBusDeployment",
          "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
              "uri": 
     "https://blob/transactiondeployment/azuredeploysvcbus.json",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
              "serviceBusNamespaceName": { "value": " [parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')]" },
              "serviceBusTopicName": { "value": "[parameters('serviceBusTopicName')]" }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
          "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
          "name": "cosmosDBDeployment",
          "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
              "uri": 
    "https://blob/transactiondeployment/azuredeploycosmosdb.json",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
              "resourceGroupPrefix": { "value": " 
   [parameters('resourceGroupPrefix')]" }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
          "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
          "name": "activateSubscriberDeployment",
          "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
          "uri": 
    "https://blob/transactiondeployment/azuredeployactivatesubscriber.json",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
              "resource_Env": { "value": "[parameters('resource_Env')]" },
              "resourceGroupPrefix": { "value": "[parameters('resourceGroupPrefix')]" },
              "typeName_FuncApp": { "value": "[parameters('typeName_FuncApp')]" },
              "serviceBusTopicName": { "value": "[parameters('serviceBusTopicName')]" },
              "ocp_apim_subscription_key": { "value": "[parameters('ocp_apim_subscription_key')]" },
              "svcbus_connection_string": { "value": "[parameters('svcbus_connection_string')]" },
          "activation_URI": { "value": "[parameters('activation_URI')]" }

            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Why the error message is 'The request URI contains an invalid name: [concat('activation-api-URI-', parameters('resource_Env'))]'.? Is there a typo `activation-api-URI-` instead of `activation-URI-` at that time ?

Comment: No sorry - that was me.  I have updated the question with the correct error

Comment: Could you show your template file?

Comment: Have added it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my validation, I also reproduce the same error.

To fix it, you could pass parameters `activation_URI` as inline values to your link template. You could try to add the referenced value to the `parameters` to tell where the secret will retrieve from. The template file will like this:

```
{
          "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
          "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
          "name": "activateSubscriberDeployment",
          "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
          "uri": 
    "https://blob/transactiondeployment/azuredeployactivatesubscriber.json",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
              "resource_Env": { "value": "[parameters('resource_Env')]" },
              "resourceGroupPrefix": { "value": "[parameters('resourceGroupPrefix')]" },
              "typeName_FuncApp": { "value": "[parameters('typeName_FuncApp')]" },
              "serviceBusTopicName": { "value": "[parameters('serviceBusTopicName')]" },
              "ocp_apim_subscription_key": { "value": "[parameters('ocp_apim_subscription_key')]" },
              "svcbus_connection_string": { "value": "[parameters('svcbus_connection_string')]" },


          "activation_URI": {
              "reference": {
              "keyVault": {
               "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/RG-DEV/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/myVault"},
              "secretName": "[concat('activation-URI-', parameters('resource_Env'))]"
  }
}

            }
          }
        }
```

The parameters file will like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        ...

        "resource_Env": {
            "value": "dev"
          }


    }
}
```

For more information, you could refer to [this template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-secrets-with-dynamic-id).